# How to count same number of elements between two arrays, excluding duplicates

Tags: arrays, for-loop, duplicates

So I have
A = {1,3,3,4}
B = {5,4,7,3}

I want to see how many times the elements of array B appear in array A, however, I only want to count each element once in array A. So if 3 appears multiple times, 3 will only be counted once, and so forth.

Here my answer would be 2, since I have 3,4 which are in array B that are also in array A.

This is what I have so far:

```
int count = 0; 
for(int z = 0; z <4; z++)
    {
      for(int y = 0; y <4; y++)
      {
         if(arrayA[z] == arrayB[y])
         {
            count++; 
         }
      }//end for loop 
    }//end for loop
```

When I run this, I get 3. I know why. I am counting duplicates in array A {3,3,4}. How do I not count them? I'm stuck.

This is a minor function that I keep getting stuck on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one simple solution could be to introduce another array to store the count and initialize it with zero (i am using c# so it would by default initialize the int array with 0).

```
int[] totals = new int[10];
int[] arrayA = new int[] { 1,3,3,4};
int[] arrayB = new int[] { 5,4,7,3};
for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
    {
        if (arrayA[z] == arrayB[y])
        {
            totals[arrayA[z]]++;
        }
    }//end for loop 
}//end for loop

// Count your numbers through indices 
for (int i = 0; i < totals.Length; i++)
{
    if (totals[i] > 0)
    {
    count++;
    }
} //end for loop
```

Comment: Now I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 50 when I try to implement my own numbers: A = 1,2,3,4 B = 2,2,2,2

Comment: can you show me your code? which language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:
Step 1: Check an element exist in an Array.
Step 2: Traverse each element in first array. Check it existed in second array and not exist in result array.

Here is my implement with `Swift`:

```
let A = [1,2,3,3,4,7]
let B = [3,4,1,2,5,7,8,3,2]
var C : [Int] = []

for (_,a) in A.enumerate() {
    if B.contains( a ) && !C.contains(a){
        C.append(a)
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I actually haven't learned the Swift function in class, so I don't think I could implement something like that in my program. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

Its easy and you can do it with (PHP language) the following:
let:

```
$A = [1,2,3,4];
$B = [2,4,6,7];
$count = 0;
$b_count = array_count_values($B);
foreach($A as $val)
{
   if(in_array($val, $B) && $b_count[$val] == 1)
   {
      $count++;
   }
}
echo "Total number of elements =>  ".$count;
```

Comment: I don't want to count duplicates, though. I'm trying to count each element in array A that appears in B once only.

Comment: For this you can slightly change the above code.
$A = [1,2,3,4];
$B = [2,4,6,7];
$count = 0;
$b_count = array_count_values($B);
foreach($A as $val)
{
    if(in_array($val, $B) && $b_count[$val] == 1)
    {
        $count++;
    }
}
echo "Total number of elements =>  ".$count;

Answer (score 1):

If you don't consider the run time complexity of the program, you can use some built-in library like map or set to code it easily, but here is

```
// complexity O( n * log(n) ), which is fast enough.
// language c++
#include<stdio.h>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, j, count = 0;
    int A[] = {1,3,3,4}, B[] = {5,4,7,3};
    int lenA = 4, lenB = 4;

    // sorting, to overlook the repeated numbers.
    sort(A, A + lenA);
    sort(B, B + lenB);

    for(i=0, j=0; i<lenA; i++)
    {
        // ignoring the repeated A elements.
        if(i>0 && A[i] == A[i-1])
            continue;

        //we can ignore all the elements of B where it's less than current A element.
        //this can be assured because of sorting.
        while(j<lenB && B[j]<A[i])
            j++;

        if(A[i] == B[j])
        {
            count++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```